# Django/Wagtail Rest API URL Filter with no response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, wagtail, wagtail-apiv2

I am using Wagtail and I have an API called `127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/stories`. In the API I am having this JSON response

```
    {
      "count": 81,
      "results": [
        {
          "id": 122,
          "title": "Test Blog",
          "blog_authors": [
            {
              "id": 82,
              "meta": {
                "type": "blog.BlogAuthorsOrderable"
              },
              "author_name": "Test",
              "author_website": null,
              "author_status": false,
         },
         {
          "id": 121,
          "title": "Test Blog 1",
          "blog_authors": [
            {
              "id": 81,
              "meta": {
                "type": "blog.BlogAuthorsOrderable"
              },
              "author_name": "Test",
              "author_website": null,
              "author_status": false,
         },
    }
```

The main problem I am fetching is that I want to filter by author name. I have done this query in the URL `?author_name=Test` & `?blog_authors__author_name=Test` & `?author__name=Test` But the response was

```
{
  "message": "query parameter is not an operation or a recognised field: author_name"
}
```

I have added these fields in `known_query_parameters` but the response was the same as `api/v2/stories/`. I have tried [DjangoFilterBackend](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) but I got the same response every time. How Can I filter by `author_name` & `author_status` in the API?

Here is my `api.py`

```
class ProdPagesAPIViewSet(BaseAPIViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
    filter_backends = [FieldsFilter,
        ChildOfFilter,
        AncestorOfFilter,
        DescendantOfFilter,
        OrderingFilter,
        TranslationOfFilter,
        LocaleFilter,
        SearchFilter,]
    known_query_parameters = frozenset(
        [
            "limit",
            "offset",
            "fields",
            "order",
            "search",
            "search_operator",
            # Used by jQuery for cache-busting. See #1671
            "_",
            # Required by BrowsableAPIRenderer
            "format",
            "page","author_name",
        ]
    )
    meta_fields = ["type","seo_title","search_description","first_published_at"]
    body_fields = ["id","type","seo_title","search_description","first_published_at","title"]
    listing_default_fields = ["type","seo_title","search_description","first_published_at","id","title","alternative_title","news_slug","blog_image","video_thumbnail","categories","blog_authors","excerpt","content","content2","tags","story_type"]
    nested_default_fields = []
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(story_type='Story').order_by('-first_published_at')
    name = "stories"
    model = AddStory

api_router.register_endpoint("stories", ProdPagesAPIViewSet)
```

For wagtails views it can be found [here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/b356fe683f49c37b9ba8838747602a5c5ecc892b/wagtail/api/v2/views.py#L37)

here is my `models.py` for blog_authors.

```
class BlogAuthorsOrderable(Orderable):
    """This allows us to select one or more blog authors from Snippets."""

    page = ParentalKey("blog.AddStory", related_name="blog_authors")
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        "blog.BlogAuthor",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    panels = [
        # Use a SnippetChooserPanel because blog.BlogAuthor is registered as a snippet
        FieldPanel("author"),
    ]

    @property
    def author_name(self):
        return self.author.name

    @property
    def author_website(self):
        return self.author.website

    @property
    def author_image(self):
        return self.author.image
    
    @property
    def author_status(self):
        return self.author.status

    api_fields = [
        APIField("author_name"),
        APIField("author_website"),
        APIField("author_status"),
        # This is using a custom django rest framework serializer
        APIField("author_image", serializer=ImageSerializedField()),
        # The below APIField is using a Wagtail-built DRF Serializer that supports
        # custom image rendition sizes
        APIField(
            "image",
            serializer=ImageRenditionField("fill-200x250|format-webp",
                source="author_image"
            )
        ),
    ]


@register_snippet
class BlogAuthor(models.Model):
    """Blog author for snippets."""


    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Special Author")
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        related_name="+",
    )

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("name"),
                # Use an ImageChooserPanel because wagtailimages.Image (image property)
                # is a ForeignKey to an Image
                FieldPanel("image"),
                FieldPanel("status"),
            ],
            heading="Name, Image and Status",
        ),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("website"),
            ],
            heading="Links"
        )
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        """String repr of this class."""
        return self.name

    class Meta:  # noqa
        verbose_name = "Blog Author"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Authors"
```

Here is how I called blog authors

```
class AddStory(Page):
    """Blog detail page."""
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                InlinePanel("blog_authors", label="Author", min_num=1, max_num=4)
            ],
            heading="Author(s)"
        ),
    
    ]
api_fields = [
        APIField("blog_authors"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a custom filter to handle your author_name parameter. Like the filters provided by Wagtail itself, it should probably inherit from `from rest_framework.filters import BaseFilterBackend`

Comment: Getting this error
`NotImplementedError: .filter_queryset() must be overridden.`

Comment: Please show the code for your new author filter. But I think the error indicates a clear next action: create a custom filter_queryset method.